# How to play custom index in JWPlayer Playlist?

Tags: ios, jwplayer, playlist

I have tried load playlist(e.g. `config.playlist = arrPlaylist`) and it is working for me ,

but when i am trying to play `customIndex` from my playlist it plays from `startIndex` only

Note: I have also add `(playerJW.playlistIndex = iCurrentPlaylistIndex)`
but not working

Comment: I am also facing same issue, please update once you get any update

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have JWPlayerController and UITableView or UICollectionView below. ( Similar view like YouTube has )

```
var player: JWPlayerController!
```

So just load your no of video objects ( array ) in UITableView or UICollectionView.

On didSelectedIndix just apply `player.stop` and again set file and play.

```
config.file = "https://URL...."
player = JWPlayerController.init(config: config)
player.play()
```